# we know how to create cron in nodejs for single timezone but i want to implement for multiple timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduler

Here is my code which runs for single time zone
but i want to run for all time zone like america,Europe,Australia

```
cron.schedule('00 49 17 * * *', function() {
        console.log("Tick");
    },{
        scheduled: true,
        timezone: "Asia/Kolkata"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe just create multiple cronjobs where you set different timezones?
I don't think you can create cronjob, that works in multiple timezones.

Comment: Not possible to create multiple cron instead i have to do anyother thing